# How to log generated sql queries out of Simple.Data ORM for .NET

Tags: .net, simple.data

How to log generated sql queries (without mysql profiler)?

I'm using Simple.Data.Mysql

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a couple of choices here. You can either set up a trace listener like this and then yes it will show up in the VS output window.

```
<configuration>
   <system.diagnostics>
      <switches>
         <add name="Simple.Data" value="Info" />
      </switches>
   </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Or you can also have a look at the [ExampleRunner](https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data.Sample/blob/master/SimpleDataSample/ExampleRunner.cs) and [ExampleTestListener](https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data.Sample/blob/master/SimpleDataSample/ExampleTestListener.cs) classes in Simple.Data.Sample for an example of setting it up in code.

Comment: In recent versions you need to write Information in value. See this line https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/simpledata/trace/simpledata/xKQyUWLqa1Y/PwOqX1znzvwJ

Answer (score 3):

All generated SQL statements (plus parameter values) are written to Trace by default, so you can just hook up a Listener.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on this answer? Am I understanding this incorrectly, or is Simple.Data supposed to automatically log all queries to the Debug Output window in Visual Studio? I can't seem to get any queries to show up there and I can't find any info about enabling it.

Comment: Are you on 0.16? There was a bug with the trace output in the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of SimpleData, to attach to Trace use:

```
SimpleDataTraceSources.TraceSource.Listeners.Add(_myTraceListener);
```