# Dynamic values in Simple.Data

Tags: simple.data

Please see below line of code for assistance.

```
private static readonly dynamic db= Database.OpenNamedConnection("DefaultConnectionString");

var idRecord = db.TableName.FindAll(db.TableName.phoneNo == phoneNo && db.TableName.password == pass).FirstOrDefault();
```

My question is, how can I see the value of `db.TableName.phoneNo` during Debug.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks.

Liaqat

Comment: Since "db.TableName.phoneNo == phoneNo" is part of the closure passed to FindAll you would have to step in at runtime when it is executed.

Comment: Thanks Tobias. I will give it a try but am in the middle of something else and will let you know if successful.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to debug this is to have the query output to the console. Then you can run it in your database. For more information, see this question. [How to log generated sql queries out of Simple.Data ORM for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289530/how-to-log-generated-sql-queries-out-of-simple-data-orm-for-net)